# Is there a concise listing of all mundane item templates?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

I know there are quite a few templates that can be added to mundane items from *Dungeon Master's Guide II* and *Hammer and Helm*, but what I'm looking for is a listing of all known templates that can be added to mundane items and its source. Is there such a listing and where might I find it if it does?

Comment: What game are you playing? Your five tags consist of four different (and completely unrelated) games, plus [tag:rpg-theory] which is just right out.

Comment: As long as it works with pretty much standard d20, I don't really care to be honest. I'm trying to figure out it its possible and okay to allow for my group to have such access to all templates or as a case by case basis. I generally prefer to go with rules as written, but there are some exceptions. Therefore I thought rpg-theory would be an appropriate place to tag my question in a broader sense. I may be mistaken for posting under dnd-bx... I thought it said "dnd-3x". I'm very familiar with both Pathfinder and D&D 3x and have some experience with other genres but am only limited to 5 tags.

Comment: Also, such a listing (if it exists at all) would be invaluable to a great number of groups for easy referencing.

Comment: *There is **no such thing** as standard d20.* 3.5 and Pathfinder are closely related and their material can be cross-applied with fairly straight-forward conversion, but other d20 System products share absolutely nothing aside from having a primary resolution mechanic of rolling a 20-sided die, adding a number, and comparing it against a target number. Even when they share terminology (as they do often do), they’re still different systems with wildly different power levels; you cannot just use them in 3.P.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “mundane item templates” – 3.5 has something called “item templates” in *Dungeon Master’s Guide II* (not PHB2), but that’s the only source of that and Pathfinder (to my knowledge) has no analogue. Or do you want to include all special materials as well, which are mundane and kind of like templates? Both 3.5 and Pathfinder have a lot of those.

Comment: You are correct. The templates you're thinking of in the DMGII is what I'm speaking of. I know green ronin press has some templates, and I believe races of the wilds, and hammer and helm have a few but the sources I do know of are very scattered. I am looking for a listing of where I could find each for easy referencing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29877/discussion-between-kryan-and-aokost).